# incomprehensible subhead of the review on Fargo

Tags: meaning

Fargo Season 3 Has Its Flaws but Has Our Attention, Too

**A casting decision and some overaggressive quirk mildly hamper an otherwise interesting installment**.

http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2017/04/fargo-season-3-review

Can you please help me with understanding the passage in bold. To tell the truth I have no clue what the critic wanted to say about the new season of TV series Fargo.

Comment: Which part don't you understand? The sentence should be read as follows: *[A casting decision and some overaggressive quirks] mildly hamper [an otherwise interesting installment].*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is terrible English.

Perhaps it could be translated to

> A poor casting decision, and overly esoteric delivery, hamper an
>   otherwise entertaining installment.

But the writing is incomprehensible, so it is impossible to know for sure.

Comment: I don't know if a couple of journalists from vanity fair came across my answer, but my point stands! overaggressive quirk mildly overaggressive quirk mildly overaggressive quirk mildly